# how can I receive notifications from firebase when the app is running?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to call notifications from firebase, and I managed to get notifications when the app is closed or in the background, but the problem is that I never get the notifications while inside the app, how can I configure firebase so that I can also give notifications while the app is running?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FireBaseNotificationController : MonoBehaviour {

public string valueTokeniD;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{       
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;       
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;        
}

public void OnTokenReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.TokenReceivedEventArgs token)
{
    valueTokeniD = token.Token;
    Debug.Log("onToken ID:" + token.Token);
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Received Registration Token: " + token.Token);
}

public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{        
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("From: " + e.Message.From);
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Message ID: " + e.Message.MessageId);        
}
```

}

Comment: Hmm... as far as I know `OnMessageReceived` is supposed to fire when you receive a message while the app is active. Is your logging output not showing up?

Comment: yes, but only in the debug ....